# Tvs diode selection for 3.3V output

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, output, tvs

Is it safe to use a TVS diode with StandOff voltage 3.3v on the output of a 3.3v regulator ?

Comment: There is probably not sufficient information to answer your question, could you please provide some context? Like a schematic or some situations where you think this might be applicable? Could you provide a specific part number?

Answer (score 1):

Depends. is the maximum clamping voltage below the maximum operating voltage of the device that is to be protected

Vwm - The working voltage. This is an indication.

Vbr(min) - the minimum voltage the TVS shall start to avalanche

Vbr(max) -  the maximum voltage the TVS shall start to avalanche

Vclamp - the maximum voltage that the TVS will clamp at Ipk

Comment: Thanks you very much , now its clear, but as I can see there arent many choices for 3.3v Tvs diodes :(

Comment: oh I know :) try protecting such lines in a waveform5 environment.  The solution is closer to CLAMP at 7V, put some RLC to "shape the remaining packet" and a fast diode to 3v3V to take the remaining charge. You need to understand what you are being exposed to